# How to manage all common components as a repository

Tags: npm, repository

We have a requirement to create common components and upload as either a npm package or repository so we can use all common components in all applications. So in future if we update any common component and same will reflect in all applications. 
Need suggestion what should we use there are options like
Lerna or create npm package for common components please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lerna along with mono repo is best option to use, where you can create packages for all common components and use in applications